# Power BI DISTINCTCOUNT in a table with value changing with slicer

Tags: powerbi, measure, slicers

I have got two separate tables. Table1 has got the data for each Contact types (A,B,C,D...) and Table2 has got the Assets in those contracts (Asset 1=A, Asset 2=A, Asset 3=C etc.).

These tables are linked.

Now, I have got a slicer to filter only A and C and I have created a table. Also, I need to disable filtering values out by Month.

I want to show total number of assets in each contract dynamically when I click on A or C in the slicer as this is important for dynamic calculations (percentage etc.). Also note, I need only A and C contract values as they are only active.

I have used the measure below, which, although gives me correct value, but the slicer for A and C are not changing the value:

**No of assets = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Table2'[Asset]),ALL('Table1'[Month]),Or('Table2'[Contract]="A",'Table2'[Contract]="C"))**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a filter visual in your report and use the following measure in a KPI card:

```
No of Assets = DistinctCount('Table2'[Asset])
```

If your relationship is correctly set and you change values on your filter/slicer, the value of the measure will change too.